# Como ordenar os Contatos por nome?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, query

Estou com o seguinte código e gostaria de fazer um ORDER BY name:

```
try {
        String clsSimPhonename = null;
        String clsSimphoneNo = null;

        Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
        Cursor cursorSim = getContentResolver().query(simUri, null,
                null, null, "name ASC");
        while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) {
            clsSimPhonename = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim
                    .getColumnIndex("name"));
            clsSimphoneNo = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim
                    .getColumnIndex("number"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiver que fazer um metodo para a ordenação:

```
public List<Telefone> ordenarTelefones(List<Telefone> lista)
        throws Exception {

    Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<Telefone>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Telefone tel1, Telefone tel2) {
            return tel1.getNome().compareTo(tel2.getNome());

        }
    });

    return lista;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o último parâmetro na *query*, mude o seu **Cursor** para algo assim:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver.query(simUri, null, null, null, "name ASC");
```

Comment: eu fiz Cursor cursorSim = getContentResolver().query(simUri, null,
     null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC"); e não mudou nada.

Comment: Ops, errei. Tente usar `"name ASC"`, este seria o `display_name` e não o `name` como você está usando e não notei.

Comment: eu já tinha testado isso também^^ não deu certo.

Comment: Dentro desse próprio `while` você tentou imprimir no console pra ver se está vindo na ordem ao menos nesse trecho? O que você faz com essas duas variáveis depois? O problema pode estar depois ainda.

Comment: dentro do while fiz ... Toast.makeText(this, clsSimPhonename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); só isso e não está ordenando por nome do contato.

Comment: É possível você listar alguns itens, os que estejam ordenados errado? Tem casos de maiúsculo/minúsculo? Já fizemos o que era necessário, não sei o que pode ser. (Com `System.out.println()` você consegue ver mais fácil no console.)

Comment: vou ver aki to fazendo os testes no meu celular... vou ver se consigo no emulador e tirar print mas acho q nao da pq nao tem cartao^^

Comment: Todos os nomes dos contatos comecam com letra maiuscula...

Comment: pronto dei um print ....

Comment: olha esse site http://www.frameworksystem.com/blog/mobile-lendo-lista-de-contatos-do-android/ eu ja fiz o teste com os contatos do celular sem ser do sim card e ordena legal... o problema só estar na ordenação dos contatos do sim card

Comment: se você possuir um celular android tente testar pra ver se no seu ordena.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18039/discussion-between-paulo-rodrigues-and-pedro-rangel).